# How many ways can the positive integer 6 be partitioned into a sum of positive integers?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I know that the number 4 can be partitioned into 5 different sums

---

5 can be partitioned into 6 different sums

---

But 6 clearly has more than 7 partitions indicating the partition function $p(n)=n+1$ only holds for $n \leq 5$

Comment: $5$ has $7$ partitions, $5, 4+1, 3+2, 3+1+1, 2+2+1, 2+1+1+1, 1+1+1+1+1$.

Comment: $p(n)=n+1$ is only true for $n=4$ and perhaps $n=0$. There are three partitions of $3$, two partitions of $2$ and one partition of $1$

Comment: the answer to the title question is $11$

Comment: See [this](http://oeis.org/A000041) for a listing of partitions

Comment: Is there a reason the answer to this question stayed in the comments instead of being answered officially? I came here for this answer (specifically the list of partitions) and was worried it didn't exist since the question is marked as "unanswered."

Answer (score 1):

$5$ has $7$ partitions, as noted by @Daniel Fischer in comments, and  $6=5+1=4+2=4+1+1=3+3=3+2+1=3+1+1+1=2+2+2=2+2+1+1=2+1+1+1+1=1+1+1+1+1+1$ has $11$ partitions.  See [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000041)